# Learning Curve with accuracy score . Overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, curve

[image]

Model overfitting ? The training score = 1 for different count of training examples (metrics - accuracy)

Comment: Yes, a training score of 1.0 *generally* indicates over-fitting.  However, it's hard to examine how that happens for you, because you've told us nothing about the application.  Are you testing with data from the training set?  Is the paradigm such that a 0.95+ cross-validation is not credible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,it seems like overfitting but the next thing you can do is  use a test set(different from your train and cross validation set) and analyze how your model generalizes on this unseen data.